# Como alterar o arquivo app.config em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#

como eu posso alterar o arquivo app.config em tempo de execução?

quero alterar a string de conexão:

```
<add name="WiconEstoqueDataContextConnectionString" connectionString="User Id=USER;Password=PASS;Host=HOST;Database=wicon_estoque;Persist Security Info=True" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, tente isto:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["WiconEstoqueDataContextConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "sua nova conexão";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Espero que isto possa ajuda-lo.